# Make login in database and change suffix if login already exists

Tags: c

I'm supposed to write a function that takes a login as argument and store this login at the end of the file named logins.db.  If the login already exists in the database, you will add the suffix 1. If the login exists with that suffix, you will try with 2, the 3... until you find a valid login.

And with this 2nd part, I get confused and my code isn't working. I'm a beginner so if you have any tips or know what code I need to add, that would be awesome. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct user
{
    char name[100];
} user;

// ************ FUNCTION SPLIT ************ //
int ft_is_separator(char c, char *charset)
{
    int    i;

    i = 0;
    while (charset[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (c == charset[i])
            return (1);
        i++;
    }
    if (c == '\0')
        return (1);
    
    return (0);
}

int ft_wordlen(char *str, char *charset)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] && !ft_is_separator(str[i], charset))
        i++;
    return (i);
}

int ft_wordcount(char *str, char *charset)
{
    int i;
    int count;

    if (!str[0])
        return (0);
    i = 1;
    count = !ft_is_separator(str[0], charset);
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (ft_is_separator(str[i - 1], charset)
            && !ft_is_separator(str[i], charset))
            count ++;
        i++;
    }
    return (count);
}

char *ft_strndup(char *src, int n)
{
    char *dest;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    dest = malloc(sizeof(char) * (n + 1));
    if (dest == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (i < n && src[i])
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}

char **ft_split(char *str, char *charset)
{
    char **table;
    int i;
    int k;

    k = 0;
    table = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (ft_wordcount(str, charset) + 1));
    if (table == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (!ft_is_separator(str[i], charset))
        {
            table[k] = ft_strndup(&str[i], ft_wordlen(&str[i], charset));
            if (table[k] == NULL)
                return (NULL);
            i = i + ft_wordlen(&str[i], charset);
            k++;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    table[k] = NULL;
    return (table);
}

// ************ FUNCTION STRCMP ************ //
int ft_strcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
     int i;
     
     i = 0;
     while (s1[i] || s2[i])
     {
         if (s1[i] != s2[i])
             return (s1[i] - s2[i]);
         i++;
     }
     return (0);
 }

// ************ FUNCTION MAIN ************ //
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fichier = NULL;
    user det;
    int recsize;
    int i = 0;

    fichier = fopen("logins.db" , "r+");
    if (fichier != NULL)
    {
        recsize = sizeof(det);
        fseek(fichier , 0 ,SEEK_END);
        printf("Enter Login : ");
        scanf("%s" , det.name);
        fprintf(fichier, "user_generator %s  \n", det.name);
        
        char **table = ft_split("logins.db" , "/n");
        printf("%s \n", table[0]);
        while (table[i])
        {
            if (ft_strcmp(table[i], det.name) == 0)
            {
                fprintf(fichier, "user_generator %s + %d \n", det.name, i);
          
            }
            i++;
        }
        
        fclose(fichier);
    }
    
    return (0);
    
}
```

Comment: May not be the end solution, but check out this line: `char **table = ft_split("logins.db" , "/n");`. I take it to mean you want to send to `ft_split()` the text contained in the database file, but you are only sending the name of the file. You need to read from the file first.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for the tips, would you know how should I send the text in the database instead of the name of the file, cause I feel that where i get stuck.

Comment: The text from the file would have to be read and put into a massive `char` array. In my opinion, it would be better to use the [fgets](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) function, which will read the next line of a file stream. This basically handles the splitting of the file into each line (marked by `\n`). You will need to rewrite some functions, but it will cut down on some implementation and utilize C's reading properties.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll check this and try to make it work :)

Comment: Also look into your use of `fseek`. This will point the start of the file stream to the end of the file, which is good for writing something to the end of the file, but bad for reading the whole file. You should seek the beginning of the file before reading each line. I also think you shouldn't be writing `det.name` to the file until you've checked that said name is not already on file (your first `fprintf`).

Comment: I have compiled these comments into an answer to make it a bit more proper.

Comment: Maybe you should learn `for()` loops, too?

Comment: You are adding users, but I think your first step is to think about the requirements and come up with a scema; how do you make it scale? Ordering by username? Next, reading the database and deserializing it in memory, then serializing and storing it to disk. Concentrate on one thing, or else it's going to be spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

In attempting to construct the table within `main`,

```
char **table = ft_split("logins.db" , "/n");
```

you are sending in the database *name*, and not the contents of the file itself. To fix this, you need to read from the file. It would not be practical to put the entire file into a single char array, because you would need to make a massive buffer to estimate just how big the database is. Instead, use the [fgets](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) function to read from the file line by line.

```
char* nextLine = fgets(buffer, maxLength, fichier);
```

You will need to change some implementation to account for this change but it will separate the file by lines, giving you the next one each time you call the function. However, before you read you need to set the `FILE*` location back to the start of the file (your `fseek()` moved the pointer to the end of the file).

Finally, you are likely to run into a problem when modifying the name of the user, as you are incrementing the suffix for every line defined in the table, and not when a username in the table matches with `det.name`. Also, if `det.name` is already in the table, you now have to check for `det.name + 1` to make sure it does not exist, and so on. This may take more than one loop as well, because the names may not necessarily be sorted.

Comment: Thanks so much for such a nice and detailed answer, I'm going to try to put everything all together. Those notions of FILE (read, write...) are new for me, so that's why I get stuck and I never used fseek before, but I'm glad to learn new stuffs. Thanks again :)